# I want to change the page view based on whether the user is an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

In rails, I have a model for users which has a flag for admins (yes, no). If the logged_in user is an admin, I'd like to be able to show different elements of the page using erb.

I'm currently doing this with logg in users vs non logged in users using this code

```
<% if current_user %>
```

But how would I specify `if current_user is admin` in the erb?

Or, is erb the best place to do this since it is exposed to the browser? If not, any suggestions for other ways to accomplish this in the model or controller?

I'm not using Devise for the user authentication currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say they have a flag, does that mean they have an attribute called `admin`?

If so, any model with a boolean in rails, you can check with:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
```

If there is another way of determining whether the user is an admin or not, you'll need to add an `admin?` method to the user class, which you can use to determine their status in the view.

Comment: I have a column name in the database called `isadmin` which is a boolean type. How do I go about creating a class?

Comment: It sounds like you already have a class with a column called `isadmin`. If that class is called `User` then you can check if they are an admin with: <% if current_user.is_admin? %>

Comment: I'm getting an undefined method error. Do I need to create a method in the Users or Application Controller?

Comment: Oops - try `<% if current_user.isadmin? %>`

Comment: If a database table (users) has a boolean attribute (isadmin) you can call the boolean with a question mark, you don't need any more methods

Comment: i.e. `User.find(2).isadmin?`

Comment: same error. I created the `isadmin` column through a migration where I just added the column. Would I need to add it anywhere else?

Comment: Have you run the migration?

Comment: rake db:migrate

Comment: I don't know what else to say... if there is a column in the users table called `isadmin` then an instance of the user class will respond to `isadmin?`

Comment: i noticed in my database that the `isadmin` column is showing as type boolean, but it's allowing me to save string values into the column

Comment: Then it's definitely not a boolean field :)

Comment: Try changing the column type with another migration

Comment: i actually changed it directly in sqlite and its still having the issue. But i figured out the issue. it's that it's an undefined method for nil:Class, so its just when there's no logged in user

Comment: Well that was a really fun hour for me. Glad you fixed your problem.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Ill accept your answer as it did work i was just chasing my tail for a while

Comment: lol no need but thanks - I didn't mean it as sarcastically as it sounded :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use user is_admin column name in views.

```
<% if current_user.is_admin? %>
```